# Getting Cookie value from MessageContext.HTTP_RESPONSE_HEADERS

Tags: java, cookies, http-headers

How can I get hold of a value of a particular cookie from list of cookies. Below is how I am trying:

```
        Map<String, List<String>> map = (Map<String, 
                List<String>>) context.get(MessageContext.HTTP_RESPONSE_HEADERS);

        List<String> contentType = getHTTPHeader(map);
        if (contentType != null) {
            StringBuffer strBuf = new StringBuffer();
            for (String type : contentType) {
                strBuf.append(type);
            }
            System.out.println("Content-Type:" + strBuf.toString());
        }

        List<String> cookies = map.get("Set-Cookie"); 
        if (cookies != null) {
            System.out.println("cookies != null");
            StringBuffer strBuf = new StringBuffer();
            for (String type : cookies) {
                System.out.println(" Looping cookie ");
                strBuf.append(type);
            }
            System.out.println("Cookie:" + strBuf.toString());
        }else{
            System.out.println("cookies == null");
        }
```

I get following results and I want to get hold of value for "JSESSIONID"

```
Cookie:JSESSIONID=88E53DE2E78TRE86E1C2B021BA240B; Path=/us-webservice
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can't you get the session id from the session itself?

Comment: What do you mean? It has been set as part of cookie and I have to read and pass it along in next request.

Comment: If you are making the requests a client like httpclient can automatically take care of handling these cookies for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cookie.substring(cookie.indexOf(':'), cookie.indexOf(';')).split("=")[1]`

or if you want regular expressions

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "JSESSIONID=([A-Z0-9]+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(cookie);
m.find();
m.group(1);
```